# Using recursion for a function with a pass by reference parameter?

Tags: c++, recursion

For my void function reverse, I have to get a string and reverse it with recursion.

So far, I have

```
void reverse(string &s)
{
    string b = s;
    s = s.substr(1) + s.at(0);
}
```

but it won't work because of the pass by reference requirement for the function.  How do I utilize the pass by reference for recursion?

Comment: Do you *have* to pass by reference?

Comment: Yes, it has to be pass by reference.

Comment: Post your real code. `s` has no type so the rest of your code is suspect. `reverse` does not return a value but you expect it to.

Comment: void reverse(string &s){
    string b = s;
    s = s.substr(1) + s.at(0);
}

Comment: It is not optimal at all; you are allocating and deallocating memory a lot (every = and +) instead of performing the replace in situ.

Comment: @oopscene Good thing optimization isn't the topic of the question or even a request to help optimize.

Comment: How is this recursive. Not calling `reverse` within `reverse`

Comment: @EdHeal It was some time ago but the code keeps changing.

Comment: @EricFortin - Wish people would not do that - makes the comments/answers meaningless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For the record, here's what the function was when I answered:**

```
void reverse(string &s)
{
    s = reverse(s.substr(1)) + s.at(0);
}
```

Multiple problems here:

First you are adding the result of `reverse` with a `char`. `reverse` returns `void` so this doesn't work. Second, substr creates a new string and passing a temp by reference is asking for trouble. Finally, in recursion, you need an exit condition. As it is, your method is crashing trying to get a substr when length is 1.

Here's a version that works:

```
void reverse(string &s)
{
    if (s.size() == 1)
        return;

    string sub = s.substr(1);
    reverse(sub);
    s = sub + s.at(0);
}
```

Comment: How does the function end its loop with s.size?  Wouldn't s stay at the size of the input?

Comment: If length of string to reverse is 1, the reverse is the same string so don't call reverse on it again or it will recurse forever.

Comment: I see.  So for s = sub + s.at(0);, the function terminates as sub empties out?  I was having problems with an infinite loop as it kept reversing nonstop.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
void _reverse(string& s, size_t z0, size_t z1)
{
    if (z1 <= z0)
        return;

    auto aux = s[z0];
    s[z0] = s[z1];
    s[z1] = aux;
    _reverse(s, z0 + 1, z1 - 1);
}


void _reverse(string& s)
{
    _reverse(s, 0, s.length() - 1);
}


int main()
{
    string x = "hello my friend";
    _reverse(x);
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: At the very least use `std::swap` to swap the values.

Comment: I can only use the given function, reverse for this assignment.

Comment: No loops and no iterators as well.